# jQuery slideshow code does not work perfectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have written a JS (jQuery) script for a slideshow. It is very simple and has just a next/previous button. Now:

PROBLEM is that the slideshow is not seamless. When I hit next/previous button it displays empty images as well. So, if I have got three images and begin navigating from image #1, something like this happens:

> 1# -> #2 -> #3 ->empty

while instead of empty it has to go back to the #1 images, but it doesn't. (instead of img I have put p)

Here is the jsFiddle Code:

http://jsfiddle.net/mostafatalebi/SG3Rq/

Here is the JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {                                          

    var x = $('.slide_top').children('p');

    x.hide();

    var i = 0;

    x.eq(i).show();

    $("#slide_next").click(function(event){ 

            event.stopPropagation();    
            event.preventDefault(); 
            x.eq(i).hide();     
            x.eq(i).next().show();  
            i = i + 1;  
            if(i === x.length)
            {
                i  = 0; 
            }

    });         
    $("#slide_prev").click(function(event){                             
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            x.eq(i).hide(); 

            x.eq(i).prev().show();      
            i = i - 1;
            if(i == x.length)
            {
                i  = 0; 
            }

    });
});
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class='slide_top'>
    <p>This is the first Paragraph</p>
    <p>This is the second Paragraph</p>
    <p>This is the third Paragraph</p>
</div>
<ul id='slide_top_click'>
    <li><a id='slide_prev' href='#' class='slide-next-icon'>Next</a></li>
    <li><a id='slide_next' href='#'  class='slide-prev-icon'>Previous</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NEXT Block:

```
  if(i == x.length){
        i  = 0; 
        x.eq(i).show();
  }
```

In PREV BLOCK

```
 if(i === 0){
      i=x.length-1;
      x.eq(i).show();
 }else{
     i = i - 1;
 }
```

Update this code in the if block. And I saw one error that you call prev method on next button and next method on prev button. Dont know whether that is your mistake or something else.

Final Code:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){                                            
        var x = $('.slide_top').children('p');
        x.hide();
        var i = 0;
        x.eq(i).show();
        $("#slide_next").click(function(event){ 
                event.stopPropagation();    
                event.preventDefault(); 
                x.eq(i).hide();     
                x.eq(i).next().show();  
                i = i + 1;  
                if(i === x.length){
                    i  = 0;  
                    x.eq(i).show();   
                }
        });         
        $("#slide_prev").click(function(event){                             
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
                alert(i);
                x.eq(i).hide(); 
                x.eq(i).prev().show();      
                if(i === 0){
                     i=x.length-1;
                     x.eq(i).show();
                }else{
                    i = i - 1;
                } 
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Good morning

I got this example working poerfectly

Just check out this for the code: `http://jsfiddle.net/5HHew/6/`

This should be your code for next and prev

```
$("#slide_next").click(function(){ 

event.stopPropagation();    
            event.preventDefault(); 
             x.eq(i).hide();
             i = i + 1;      


            if(i === x.length)
            {
                i  = 0; 

            }   

    x.eq(i).show();
    });         
    $("#slide_prev").click(function(event){                             
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
             x.eq(i).hide();
             i = i - 1;      


            if(i === -1)
            {
                i  = x.length - 1; 

            }             
     x.eq(i).show();

    });     });
```

also, you swopped your events around

Goodluck!